# Each line of column in file as key in awk

Tags: bash, awk

Thanks to **@jxc** I was able to get a working code in post:

> Bash loop to make directory, if numerical id found in file

I'm trying to use `awk` to create sub-directories in a directory which will already be created in `/path/to/directory`. If the full string in `$2` of `file1` is found in `$0`, second line (always this format) of `file2`. There will be more lines in `file2` then matches.

The directory will already be created in `/path/to/directory`. In the example below,
SubDirectory already exists in `/path/to/directory` and since `19-0000_Lname-yy-zzz` and `19-0001_Lname-yyyy-zzzzz` are found in `$2` of `file1`, they are created in the subDirectory. Thank you :).

I thought of, maybe these two lines:

```
a[substr($i,1,length($2)]
```

then

```
 { k = substr($0, 1, length[a] }
```

**file1**

```
xxxx_006 19-0000_Lname-yy-zzz
xxxx_007 19-0001_Lname-yyyy-zzzzz
SubDirectory -- always the last line of file1--
```

**file2**

```
xxxx
19-0003-xxx-xxx-xxx_000-111
yyyy
xxxx
19-0000_Lname-yy-zzz_000-111
yyyy
xxxx
19-0001_Lname-yyyy-zzzzz_000-111
yyyy
```

**Desired sub-directory**

```
SubDirectory
19-0000_Lname-yy-zzz_000-111
19-0001_Lname-yyyy-zzzzz_000-111
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$2]; next} ($1 FS $2) in seen' file1 FS=_ file2
```

```
19-0000_Lname-yy-zzz_000-111
19-0001_Lname-yyyy-zzzzz_000-111
```

Alternatively this should also work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$2]; next} {s=$0; sub(/_[^_]+$/, "", s)} s in seen' file1 FS=_ file2
```

Comment: To create directories use `awk ... | xargs mkdir`